# Porous silicon simulator

Tags: simulation, software, silicon

What software does porous silicon simulations?
I didn't find it in my searches. The closest was TCAD Atlas, but it gives more prominence to cmos. I would like to know if there is (names) software that makes porous silicon simulations: porous size, cavities, filling of chemical elements, reactions etc.

Comment: Isn't there a chemistry or solid state physics group on stackexchange, somewhere? Or is there an electronics bit to this that I'm missing?

Comment: @jonk There's a surprisingly specific Matter Modelling Stack Exchange. There's a Chemistry and Physics one too, but I suspect this question is out of their depth.

Comment: @DKNguyen Well, I'm still searching those words for something 'electronic'. See anything there of that ilk?

Comment: @jonk Try searching silicon instead. That SE is super strange to me. Even more than the math one.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yeah. So copper is also used in electronics. But if I asked a question about making super-cooled quantum-entangled copper nanotubes, I probably would *not* be asking the question here. Even if it was just a software question... I'd probably go to your excellently suggested Matter Modelling group!

Comment: Microelectronics is associated with porous silicon, it is related to electronics, yes. How do you think semiconductors are created?
Chemistry is closely related to electronics, gentlemen, do you leave basic electronics?
You do not know about my question, no problem for me, but to say that PSi not electronics is CONCERNED.